# Postgres - how to enforce NUMERIC value between 1 & 10

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL I have a column `city_rate` value `NUMERIC DEFAULT 1.00`.

Is there a way from postgres to enforce that value to be between two values: 1.00 & 10.00.

Like if user INSERT or UPDATE `city_rate` with a value greater than 10.00 it will save it as 10.00, or if the value is lower than 1.00 it will be saved as 1.00.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a check constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE yourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT rate_check CHECK (city_rate >= 1.0 AND city_rate <= 10.00);
```